# How can I clean the publish folder so a DLL doesn't keep getting copied to my website?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nuget, visual-studio-2019

When building my solution, the most recent (v6.2.1) RabbitMQ.Client.dll ends up here:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\RabbitMQ.Client.dll

I don't want that version. I referenced the latest RabbitMQ.Client.dll DLL in a project, by mistake, then undid that and referenced a previous version (v5.1.2), but the new one keeps showing up in wwwroot when building (we have a post-build event that publishes).

I cleared the NuGet cache, but it's still happening.

I searched for RabbitMQ.Client.dll in our solution folder and found these, all v6.2.1 (the new one, not what I want), in every one of our projects:
bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\publish\RabbitMQ.Client.dll

Is there a way to clear that folder? I'm guessing that's why the wrong version keeps ending up in wwwroot when building/publishing. Running Clean, in VS, doesn't do it.

Comment: Is RabbitMQ still in the packages.config or one of it's dependencies?

Comment: We use the newer PackageReference and all references are the older version, which is what we want.

Comment: I deleted the `netcoreapp2.2` folder, did a rebuild, and the file is the correct version now in the publish folder. It would be nice if this happened automatically, but if I have to manually delete the folders this one time, so be it. Time to get back to work...

Comment: @BobHorn,any update about it?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I have a reminder to check this on Monday when I'm back at work. Thank you for the tip. It looks good and I will give it a shot.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT By the way, do you know why the default behavior doesn't clear that folder? Is there a reason for it?

Comment: clean button will clean the build output files rather then publish files. You can interpret it as clean, build is a pair, and Publish is another operation that is not part of Clean's processing. This is a normal phenomenon. So if you want to delete the Publish folder, you need to add an automated target. My goal is that delete the previous publish folder after you click publish button. Because the `Publishurl` is obtained during publication, it is better for you to set the delete action in `publish` rather than `Clean`.

Comment: Right, I get that. I meant why doesn't a publish clear files first by default? That just means old files can remain and cause issues like the one I'm having.

Comment: Sure. It is quite an issue and should be automatic to remove the previous and then use the latest used ones. From a purely vs usage point of view, this is an obvious issue. I have updated my answer and please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an automated MSBuild target to every your project's csproj file.

```
   <Target Name="DeletePreviousPublish" BeforeTargets="_CheckForUnsupportedTargetFramework">

    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishUrl.Remove($(PublishDir.LastIndexOf('\'))))"></RemoveDir>

   </Target>
```

If your `$(PublishDir)` ends with `\`, you should use `$(PublishDir.LastIndexOf('\')))` to make it as a folder so that **RemoveDir** will work.

If not, just use

`<RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishDir)"></RemoveDir>`.

**And** then, when you click **Publish** button, it will first remove the previous publish folder and generate the new one. It is automatic, so you no longer need to manually delete the folder.

**Update 1**

It is quite an issue and should be automatic to remove the previous and then use the latest used ones. From a purely vs usage point of view, this is an obvious issue. I have reported [the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1297030/why-publish-button-cannot-clean-the-previous-refer.html).

You can vote it and add any comments under the link if I did not describe the issue in detail. And hope the Team will fix the issue.

**Since** the process will take a long time and for now, you have to use my solution to get what you want.

Comment: FYI, first attempt produces this error: "The expression """.Remove(-1)" cannot be evaluated. StartIndex cannot be less than zero." A second build produces no error, but a rebuild causes the same error.

Comment: Using this line seems to work: `<RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishDir)"></RemoveDir>`

Comment: I actually ended up doing this in the post-build event of the project: `RD /S /Q "$(PublishDir)"`

Comment: For completeness, it looks like there was an issue with PublishUrl vs PublishDir: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/3708.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and sharing the deep research. Looks like `$(PublishDir)` is more better. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use `BeforeTargets="Build"`

```
  <Target Name="DeletePublish" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Delete the Publish Folder: $(PublishDir)" Importance="high"></Message>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishDir)" />
  </Target>
```